# Extracting correct values form input tag .. images provided :)

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I’m using scrapy crawl spider and trying to parse output pages to select some input tag parameter( type , id , name ) , each data type is selected into an item so that it will be stored in Database later something like that :

```
 Database Table_1
 ╔════════════════╗
 ║      text      ║ 
 ╠════════════════╣
 ║  id  │ name    ║ 
 ╟──────┼─────────╢
 ║      │         ║ 
 ╟──────┼─────────╢
 ║      │         ║ 
 ╚══════╧═════════╝
```

the same will be in password and file but ,

The problem i face is that xpath extracts the whole tag  !!

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from isa.items import IsaItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['testaspnet.vulnweb.com']
    start_urls = ['http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com']


    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/*' ) ),callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('%s' % response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item=IsaItem()
        text_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]").extract()
        pass_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]").extract()     
        file_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'file')]").extract()

        print text_input , pass_input ,file_input  
        return item
```

**Output**

```
me@me-pc:~/isa/isa$ scrapy crawl example.com -L INFO -o file_nfffame.csv -t csv
2012-07-02 12:42:02+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: isa)
2012-07-02 12:42:02+0200 [example.com] INFO: Spider opened
2012-07-02 12:42:02+0200 [example.com] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),    scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
[u'<input name="tbUsername" type="text" id="tbUsername" class="Login">'] [u'<input name="tbPassword" type="password" id="tbPassword" class="Login">'] []
[] [] []
[u'<input name="tbUsername" type="text" id="tbUsername" class="Login">'] [u'<input name="tbPassword" type="password" id="tbPassword" class="Login">'] []

[] [] []
2012-07-02 12:42:08+0200 [example.com] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: What should the correct output look like?

Comment: @stav for     type text >> [id , name], for type password  [id ,name ] , exactly ["tbUsername", "tbUsername"], ["tbPassword","tbPassword"] , i know there is a duplicated values but this since this form id =name

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you want to extract attribute values from inputs.

Your current XPath is giving you whole nodes because that's what you're asking for. The XPath selectors go up to the point of a node, but not beyond it to a particular attribute of that node.

To get a node's `id` attribute rather than the node itself:

```
some/xpath/query/@id
```

Comment: can you apply your solution to my xpath kindly ?

Comment: I was just showing you the principle. To extract an attribute value, append `/@attr_name` to your current XPath.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//yourCurrentExpression/@id
```

to obtain the `id` attributes.

**Use**:

```
//yourCurrentExpression/text()
```

to obtain the text-node child of any selected by `yourCurrentExpression` element.

**Finally, you could combine the two expressions into a single one**:

```
//yourCurrentExpression/@id | //yourCurrentExpression/text()
```

This produces a node-list where its items are ordered like: `(id-attribute, text-node)*`, in other words the selected nodes are represented in document order.

Comment: $  text_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id and @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id").extract()
    pass_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id and @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()  
    file_input=hxs.select("//input[(@id and @name) and (@type = 'file')]/@id").extract()     >> this gave me only id     [u'tbUsername'] [u'tbPassword'] []

Comment: @right.sowrd: You need to know at least minimum XPath in order to be able to substitute your XPath expression into a more general one. I think you made the substitution incorrectly, but it is difficult to read from your comment. You may edit your question and put these there -- or ask a new question. As I mentioned, it is best if you learn the minimum XPath before asking questions here -- otherwise you would not be able to understand and apply the answers -- as this case clearly shows.

Comment: @right.sowrd: Actually, from your comment I see that you haven't even used the XPath expressions from my answer ...